# Execute CURL command in java 8

Tags: curl, java-8, inputstream

Just I have one problem and probably you could help me, I am trying to execute CURL command in Java 8, I have my code when I am running is getting empty as a response in this line

> writer.toString();

, but if I run that command in terminal is working, so not proxy issues.

But if I am using Curl with -o, I am creating temporal files on server but this is not good because I have hundreds of link that I have to validate, someone knows what I am missing here?

```
String url = "https://" + serverName + ":" + port + "/api/doc.json";


            serviceRecord.setHost(lstHost);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -k " + url);
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");

            String text = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Why use `curl`? Since Java 11, we have a [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) that ships with Java. For usage examples, see [this tutorial at `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client).

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the project that I have is big one and it is in java 8, so I have to add those additional functionalities yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a curl conversion to java.
I'm not a java guy.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://example.com:80/api");
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        InputStream responseStream = httpConn.getResponseCode() / 100 == 2
                ? httpConn.getInputStream()
                : httpConn.getErrorStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(responseStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
        String response = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```